# Add image stored as byte array to PDF using PDFBox

Tags: java, spring, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to insert an image into a PDF using PDFBox. Image insertion is pretty straightforward in PDFBox if the image is saved as a file using

```java
// Insert saved image
PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("C:/logo.png", doc);
```

However, in my case, I am generating the image within the code as a `BufferedImage` object. I could save the image first as a file and insert it from there, however, I have to generate a lot of these images and such an approach isn't feasible.

How can I insert an image stored as a `BufferedImage`, `byte array`, or any other "in-code" representation, into a PDF using PDFBox?

Answer (score 2):

In the package [`org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.13/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/package-summary.html) you'll find a couple of factory methods to create `PDImage` objects. The one you are interested in is [`LosslessFactory#createFromImage`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.13/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/LosslessFactory.html#createFromImage-org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument-java.awt.image.BufferedImage-), which accepts a `BufferedImage` as parameter.

Comment: also `PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray()` if the file exists as a byte array.